# WordPress v3.5.1 collapsible menu missing

Tags: wordpress, web, menu

I have Admin role but the collapsible menu (left side panel) is missing, I tried to create another admin but still no avail. I can access WP file when I type it as URL (ex http://xxx-xxx.com/wp-admin/plugins.php) Please help I'm still a newbie.

Thanks you very much!

Comment: Did you recently install or modify a theme or plugin? Did the panel appear before, and only recently disappear? Can you account for any changes to your installation (like new themes and so on) that might have occurred around the time the problem arose?

Comment: Hi @raphaelvalerio

Thanks to your reply. Unfortunately, the WP site that I'm mentioning is just turnover to me. I just got employed (just saying*) and know nothing about the history of the site.

What I did, first I used the admin acct of former programmer, I thought its just on his acct thats why I made my own admin account - But still no panel. And all plugins are updated.

Thanks again.

Comment: So this problem existed from the start for you? You might want to check the functions.php file for the installed theme. Look to see if there is any PHP code that starts with the line `if(is_admin())`. One of these may be affecting the admin area, or a function intended for the front end may be screwing with the admin area and need `if (!is_admin())` wrapped around it. Are you familiar with this sort of WordPress stuff?

Comment: It's working! You're right! Its on theme's functions.php. I just comment the line that saying "remove_menu"

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: You're welcome! I'll add a modified version of my comment as an answer, so you can tag if as being helpful. That way other users who find the page know what the right answer was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check the functions.php file for the installed theme. Look to see if there is any PHP code that starts with the line `if(is_admin())`. One of these may be affecting the admin area, or a function intended for the front end may be screwing with the admin area and need if `(!is_admin())` wrapped around it. Are you familiar with this sort of WordPress stuff?

NOTE: we talked through the problem in the comments, so I added the answer formally here.

(The theme's functions.php had a `remove_menu()` line, which was commented out to restore the admin sidebar menu.)